# Want to scrape table using Puppeteer. How can I get all rows, iterate through rows, and then get "td's" for each row?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have Puppeteer setup, and I was able get all of the rows using:

```
let rows = await page.$$eval('#myTable tr', row => row);
```

Now I want for each row to get "`td`'s" and then get the `innerText` from those.

Basically I want to do this:

```
var tds = myRow.querySelectorAll("td");
```

Where `myRow` is a table row, with Puppeteer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use evaluate that first gets an array of all the `TD`s then returns the `textContent` of each `TD`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <body>
      <table>
      <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Three</td><td>Four</td></tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td'))
    return tds.map(td => td.innerText)
  });

  //You will now have an array of strings
  //[ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' ]
  console.log(data);
  //One
  console.log(data[0]);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

You could also use something like:

```js
const data = await page.$$eval('table tr td', tds => tds.map((td) => {
  return td.innerText;
}));

//[ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' ]
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 40):

### Two-Dimensional Array Method

You can also scrape the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) into a **two-dimensional array** representing your table.

```
[
  ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'], // Row 1
  ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'], // Row 2
  ['A3', 'B3', 'C3']  // Row 3
]
```

---

#### page.$$eval()

```
const result = await page.$$eval('#example-table tr', rows => {
  return Array.from(rows, row => {
    const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
  });
});

console.log(result[1][2]); // "C2"
```

#### page.evaluate()

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#example-table tr');
  return Array.from(rows, row => {
    const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
  });
});

console.log(result[1][2]); // "C2"
```

Comment: Your answer helped me. But in my case, I had to use `column.textContent` instead of `column.innerText`, otherwise I was getting back blank cells.

Comment: This generated many arrays full \n \n \n \n  :( (That in booking.com)

Comment: @JohnHarris did you try `column.textContent.trim()`?

Answer (score 4):

A 2D array one-liner:

```
let results = await page.$eval('table tbody', tbody => [...tbody.rows].map(r => [...r.cells].map(c => c.innerText)))
```