# Scraping table to get specific data using puppeteer

Tags: html, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
<tbody class="ant-table-tbody">
  <tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
    <td class>
      <span class="ant-table-row-indent indent-level-0" style="padding-left: 0px;"</span>
      "Bombay"
      </td>
    <td class>
       <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="ant-checkbox ant-checkbox-checked">
           <input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value="on">
       </label>
     </td>
    <td class>
       <div>
         <i class ="anticon anticon-delete">
           ::before
         </i>
       </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">...<tr>
```

I have this table structure where there are three separate `<td>` for each `<tr>` row. I am trying to find the following using puppeteer

- text inside the first `<td>`
- count the number of second `<td>` tags that has `<span>` element with the class `"ant-checkbox-checked"`.

Right now I can get all the text (inside all the tr and td ) using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236981/want-to-scrape-table-using-puppeteer-js-how-can-i-get-all-rows-iterate-through)

```
 const data = await page.evaluate(()=>{
            const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr td'));
            return tds.map(td => td.innerText);
        });
        console.log(data);
```

But this returns all text data , which I don't need and I need only the specific data. How to drill down inside the specific tags using puppeteer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to obtain the text content of the first column, and then you can use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) to count the number of [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements in the second column containing the class `ant-checkbox-checked`:

```
let first_column_text = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ant-table-tbody > .ant-table-row > td:first-child'), element => element.textContent.trim()));
let second_column_checked_count = (await page.$$('.ant-table-tbody > .ant-table-row > td:nth-child(2) > .ant-checkbox-wrapper > span.ant-checkbox-checked')).length;
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Works perfectly. :)