# How to get text from a specific column from a table in Playwright

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright

I am using Playwright for the e2e tests. The problem statement that I have is that I want to get the text contents of all the rows of a specific column of a table. The table in question is just like the ones displayed here - https://ant.design/components/table/

A similar HTML ->
[image: HTML of table]

(although each `td` inside the `tr` has a different class in my case).

Let's just say if I want to get all the age from the Age column in the table.

I've tried a couple of approaches but all of them end up with Promise rejected or Promise waiting and the test times out.

Eg -

```
let table_row = page.locator("tbody.ant-table-tbody tr");   // get the tr tags
       let text = table_row.locator('td:nth-child(2)');
       const arrayoftext = await page.$$eval(text, links=>
           links.map(link.textContent) )
```

I've asked a similar question related to Puppeteer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535319/scraping-table-to-get-specific-data-using-puppeteer) but I am trying to approach this in a more Playwright-y way using `page.locator` if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Playwright 1.21 there is a new method was introduced called the `:scope`. You can read more about it [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#augmenting-existing-locators). Using this your can optimize your code like this:

```js
const row = page.locator('tbody.ant-table-tbody tr[data-row-key="3"]')
const rowTexts = await row.locator(':scope').allInnerTexts()
await rowTexts.forEach((text) => {
  console.log(text)
})
```

Comment: Marked this as expected answer. Although can we use map/filter in the same to achieve the result?

Comment: Yes, you can, but if I understood correctly from your question, you were looking for something that solves the problem using playwright commands. This is the closest I could get.

Comment: Link to :scope is dead, also I don't see how it helps say getting all values of column 2 of the table

Answer (score 4):

```
const textsFromThirdColumn = [];    
const rowCount = await page.locator('.ant-table-tbody').locator('tr').count();

for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
textsFromThirdColumn.push(await page.locator('.ant-table-tbody').locator('tr').nth(i).locator('td').nth(2).innerText())
}
```

Comment: Sorry I may have incorrectly explained the question. I want to get the text from all rows of a specific column. This would work fine for a single column, single row. How do I get this for all rows?

Comment: You can just use a for loop. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

In latest playwright, you can simply do to get and verify text in single step:

```
expect(page.locator('.my-table-row').nth(2)).toContainText('Steve')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayName = new Array<string>();
let count = await page.locator('tr').count();
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
  let name : string;
  name  = await page.locator('tr').nth(i).locator('td').nth(0).locator(':scope').allInnerTexts();
  name = name.toString();
  arrayName.push(name);
}
console.log(arrayName);
```

NB : nth(0) -> need to be customized based on the column which you need to get data from