# Puppeteer page.evaluate a table into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a table that you can see below. I'm trying to make an array of contents inside each `<tr>` element. For example an array would output like

```
[{Current: 757, Peak: 976, Name: XXX},{Current: 594, Peak: 684, Name: XXX2}]
```

Any insight would greatly be appreciated as to what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<div id="detail">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td align="right"><b>Peak</b></td>
        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left"><b>Name</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="count_row">
        <td align="right">
          <span class="current">757</span>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <span class="current">976</span>
        </td>
        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <a class="nameLink" href="xxx">XXX</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="count_row">
        <td align="right">
          <span class="current">594</span>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <span class="current">684</span>
        </td>
        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <a class="nameLink" href="xxx">XXX2</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
let scrape = async() => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://xxx/stats/`, {
      waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    })
    const gameRecordsList = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let record = {
        'name': '',
        'current': '',
        'peak': ''
      }
      let nameCountList = []
      const row = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('#detail > table > tbody > tr > td')
      )
      record.name = (row.map(td => td[2].innerText))
      record.current = (row.map(td => td[0].innerText))
      record.peak = (row.map(td => td[1].innerText))
      if (row.length >= 200) {
        nameCountList.push(record)
      }
      return nameCountList;
    });
    browser.close();
    console.log(gameRecordsList)
  } catch (err) {
    // Catch and display errors
    console.log(error(err));
    console.log(error("Error, Browser Closed"));
  }
};
scrape()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scraping tables, if you first select by `td`s it can be difficult to cleanly re-assemble the rows.

I would first select the row elements, then for each row, select the cells. This produces a 2d array that's much easier to manipulate.

After that, you can use a simple `map` to create the array of objects.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^16.2.0

const html = `<div id="detail"> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td align="right"><b>Current</b></td> <td align="right"><b>Peak</b></td> <td width="20">&nbsp;</td> <td align="left"><b>Name</b></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr class="count_row"> <td align="right"> <span class="current">757</span> </td> <td align="right"> <span class="current">976</span> </td> <td width="20">&nbsp;</td> <td> <a class="nameLink" href="xxx">XXX</a> </td> </tr> <tr class="count_row"> <td align="right"> <span class="current">594</span> </td> <td align="right"> <span class="current">684</span> </td> <td width="20">&nbsp;</td> <td> <a class="nameLink" href="xxx">XXX2</a> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

  const data = (
    await page.$$eval("#detail tr", (els) =>
      els
        .slice(2)
        .map((e) =>
          [...e.querySelectorAll("td")].map((e) => e.textContent.trim())
        )
    )
  ).map(([current, peak, , name]) => ({current, peak, name}));

  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

A more general approach is to filter out empty cells:

```js
const data = (
  await page.$$eval("#detail tr", (els) =>
    els
      .slice(2)
      .map((e) =>
        [...e.querySelectorAll("td")]
          .map((e) => e.textContent.trim())
          .filter(Boolean)
      )
  )
).map(([current, peak, name]) => ({current, peak, name}));
```

See also:

- [Want to scrape table using Puppeteer. How can I get all rows, iterate through rows, and then get "td's" for each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236981/want-to-scrape-table-using-puppeteer-how-can-i-get-all-rows-iterate-through-ro)
- [How to automatically scrape table rows for specific columns with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985397/how-to-automatically-scrape-table-rows-for-specific-columns-with-puppeteer/72987700#72987700)

Comment: incredible. thank you so much.