# use puppeteer to scrape paragraph inner text and image title from table td

Tags: html-table, puppeteer, element, href, scrape

[image: table]

I have a table with this structure.
and i want to scrape from the td with class 'description' the image title and the text from paragraph.
I have tried several ways with no luck.
Please help me on this guys i am really stacked here.

I think my question is very clear but so far i have

```js
 let descs = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let desc = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.even td.description p'))
        return desc.filter((p) => p.innerText !== "").map(p => p.innerText.replace((/  |\r\n|\n|\r/gm),""));
   });
```

With this code i am getting the paragraph text but how can i get  the img title also?

Comment: Please share your several attempts and exact expected output, as well as the page itself. Thanks. Did you try [checking an existing question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236981/want-to-scrape-table-using-puppeteer-how-can-i-get-all-rows-iterate-through-ro)

Comment: Use the same logic, just change the selector to match the image. ex: "tr.even td.description a img" - and fetch the title attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By provided HTML structure i suggest to get td element and perform `$$eval` with mapping on it.

Where texts is your function that was defined for `p` and `title` you are getting by `querySelector` with `img[src]` selector from `td` element.

````js
await page.waitForSelector('tr.even td.description');
const data = await page.$$eval('tr.even td.description', tds =>
      tds.map(td => {
        return {
          texts: Array.from(td.querySelectorAll('p')).filter((p) => p.innerText !== "").map(p => p.innerText.replace((/  |\r\n|\n|\r/gm),"")),
          title: td.querySelector('img[src]')?.getAttribute('title'),
        }
      })
    );```
````